Save bookmark+ URL bookmarks to a separate file
I am looking for a way to manage browser bookmarks with Emacs. It seems bookmark+ URL bookmarks will do the job. I was wondering, is it possible to store URL bookmarks in a different file, or even have different files for different types of bookmarks provided by bookmark+?

Yes. You can have any number of bookmark files, and any bookmark file can contain bookmarks of any kind. So you can, for example, have a bookmark file that contains only URL bookmarks. See Using Multiple Bookmark Files.
You can also have bookmark-file bookmarks, which, when jumped to, load particular bookmark files. So you can, for example, jump to such a bookmark that loads or switches to your URL bookmarks.
See also Bookmark Files For Bookmarks with Specific Tags.
